# Is there any way to go back in terminal where I left off?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I am new to terminal and I just wanted to know if there's any way I could start from where I left off to avoid typing the whole commands again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there is. This is the main feature of `GNU Screen`, and also of `tmux` - choosing one is a matter of preference.

Comment: Will it work after I restart computer and try to restore the terminal session?

Comment: If your session is running on the restarted computer, then no: screen's sessions are temporary and cleared at reboot.